# One optional argument which does not require positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have a question regarding python's argparse: Is it possible to have a optional argument, which does not require positional arguments?

Example:

```
parser.add_argument('lat', help="latitude")
parser.add_argument('lon', help="longitude")
parser.add_argument('--method', help="calculation method (default: add)", default="add")
parser.add_argument('--list-methods', help="list available methods", action="store_true")
```

The normal command line would be `test.py 47.249 -33.282` or `test.py 47.249 -33.282 --method sub`. But as soon as I call the script with `test.py --list-methods` to list all available methods, I get `error: to few arguments`. How can I use argparse to have this optional argument (--list-methods) without having positional arguments (lat, lon)?

Comment: You could add default=None to lat and lon, and then check for None in your code...

Comment: Since you don't set `nargs` it looks like at lot of these are required.  Why don't have nave `nargs='?'` set for the optional arguments?

Answer (score 4):

- set a default value and `nargs='?'` for your positional arguments
- check manually in your code that both *latitude* and *longitude* have been set when you're not in *list-methods* mode

  ```
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

  parser.add_argument('lat', help="latitude",default=None, nargs='?')
  parser.add_argument('lon', help="longitude",default=None, nargs='?')
  parser.add_argument('--method', help="calculation method (default: add)", default="add")
  parser.add_argument('--list-methods', help="list available methods", action="store_true")

  args = vars(parser.parse_args())

  if not args['list_methods'] and (args['lat'] == None or args['lon'] == None):
      print '%s: error: too few arguments' % sys.argv[0]
      exit(0)

  if args['list_methods']:
      print 'list methods here'
  else :
      print 'normal script execution'
  ```

which gives :

> $ test.py --list-methods
>   list  methods here
>
> $ test.py 4
>   test.py: error: too few arguments
>
> test.py 4 5
>   normal script execution

Answer (score 2):

As of Python 3.3, `parse_args` checks its set of `seen_actions` against the set of actions that are required, and issues a `the following arguments are required...` error as needed.  Previously it checked its list of remaining `positionals` and raised the `too few arguments` error message.

So for newer versions, this snippet should do what you want:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
lat=parser.add_argument('lat', help="latitude")
lon=parser.add_argument('lon', help="longitude")
parser.add_argument('--method', help="calculation method (default: add)", default="add")

class MyAction(argparse._StoreTrueAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const)
        lat.required = False
        lon.required = False

parser.add_argument('--list-methods', help="list available methods", action=MyAction)
```

Normally `lat` and `lon` are required positionals, but if the `--list...` action is taken, those actions are no longer required, and no error message is raised if they are missing.

---

Another way to customize argparse is to use several parsers.  In this case you could use one parser to check for the `--list-methods` option, and based on what it gets, call another that looks for the positionals.

```
parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser1.add_argument('--list-methods', help="list available methods", action='store_true')

parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser2.add_argument('lat', help="latitude")
parser2.add_argument('lon', help="longitude")
parser2.add_argument('--method', help="calculation method (default: add)", default="add")
parser2.add_argument('--list-methods', help="list available methods", action='store_true')
def foo(argv):
    args,rest = parser1.parse_known_args(argv)
    if not args.list_methods:
        args = parser2.parse_args(argv)
    return args
```

`parser2` responds to the help command.  `parse_known_args` parses what it can, and returns the rest in a list.  `parser2` could also have been write to take `rest, args` as arguments.

Comment: i was a bit disaponted with the flow and side effect, so here is my proposal for a wrapper:
```
def positional_discarder(args_to_discard):
    class DiscardPositionalInput(argparse.Action):
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
            for arg in args_to_discard:
                arg.required = False

    return DiscardPositionalInput
```
then
```parser.add_argument('--list-methods', help="list available methods", action=positional_discarder([lat,long]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You get `error: to few arguments` because `lat` and `lon` arguments are required.

```
In [10]: parser.parse_args('--list-methods'.split())
ipython: error: too few arguments
```

but

```
In [11]: parser.parse_args('--list-methods 10 20'.split())
Out[11]: Namespace(lat='10', list_methods=True, lon='20', method='add')
```

You should make `lat` and `lon` arguments optional.