# Argparse: ignore multiple positional arguments when optional argument is specified

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to make argparse ignore the fact that two normally required positional arguments shouldn't be evaluated when an optional argument (`-l`) is specified.

Basically I'm trying to replicate the behavior of --help: when you specify the -h, all missing required arguments are ignored.

Example code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Foo bar baz")
parser.add_argument('arg1', help='arg1 is a positional argument that does this')
parser.add_argument('arg2', help='arg2 is a positional argument that does this')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', dest='list', help='this is an optional argument that prints stuff')

options, args = parser.parse_args()

if options.list:
   print "I list stuff"
```

And of course, if I run it now, I get :

```
error: too few arguments
```

I tried different things like `nargs='?'`, but couldn't get anything working.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880169/one-optional-argument-which-does-not-require-positional-arguments) is quite similar but wasn't answered.

Comment: Alix, I added a response to the similar question you mentioned in your post. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, `argparse` isn't quite flexible enough for this.  The best you can do is to make `arg1` and `arg2` optional using `nargs="?"` and check yourself whether they are given if needed.

The internal `help` action is implemented by printing the help message and exiting the program as soon as `-h` or `--help` are encountered on the command line.  You could write a similar action yourself, something like

```
class MyAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, values, namespace, option_string):
        print "Whatever"
        parser.exit()
```

(Warning: untested code!)

There are definite downsides to the latter approac, though.  The help message will unconditionally show `arg1` and `arg2` as compulsory arguments.  And parsing the command line simply stops when encountering `-l` or `--list`, ignoring any further arguments.  This behaviour is quite acceptable for `--help`, but is less than desirable for other options.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue and decided to use subcommands. Subcommands might be overkill, but if you find your program not using some of the positional arguments in many instances (as I did), then subcommands might be a good solution.

For your given example, I'd use something like the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Foo bar baz")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(description='available subcommands')

parser_main = subparsers.add_parser('<main_command_name>')
parser_main.add_argument('arg1', help='arg1 is a positional argument that does this')
parser_main.add_argument('arg2', help='arg2 is a positional argument that does this')

parser_list = subparsers.add_parser('list', help='this is a subcommand that prints stuff')

options, args = parser.parse_args()
```

I left out some details that you might want to include (like `set_defaults(func=list)`), which are mentioned in the [argparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest approach I've been able to find so far is to split the parsing into two stages. First check for `-l/--list`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Foo bar baz")
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', dest='list', action='store_true',
                    help='this is an optional argument that prints stuff')

options, remainder = parser.parse_known_args()
```

Now, since you used `parse_known_args`, you won't get an error up to here, and you can decide what to do with the `remainder` of the arguments:

```
if options.list:
    print "I list stuff"
else:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('arg1', help='arg1 is a positional argument that does this')
    parser.add_argument('arg2', help='arg2 is a positional argument that does this')
    options = parser.parse_args(remainder)
```

You may want to set the usage option in the first parser to make the help string a bit nicer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `nargs='*'` is helpful.

Positional arguments is ignorable, then you can use `if` to check the positional arguments is true or false.

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#nargs

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution here. True, it is a dirty hack, but it works.

***Note: all the following applies to Python 3.3.2.***

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17895206/851560), `parse_args` checks which actions are required and throws an error if any of them are missing. I propose to override this behavior.

By subclassing `ArgumentParser` we can define a new `ArgumentParser.error` method (original [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Lib/argparse.py#l2355)) that will check whether the error was thrown because some arguments are missing and take necessary action. Code follows:

```py
import argparse
import sys
from gettext import gettext as _

class ArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    skip_list = []

    def error(self, message):
        # Let's see if we are missing arguments
        if message.startswith('the following arguments are required:'):
            missingArgs = message.split('required: ')[1].split(', ')
            newArgs = []    # Creating a list of whatever we should not skip but is missing
            for arg in missingArgs:
                if arg not in self.skip_list:
                    newArgs.append(arg)
                else:
                    self.skip_list.remove(arg)  # No need for it anymore
            if len(newArgs) == 0:
                return  # WARNING! UNTESTED! MAY LEAD TO SPACETIME MELTDOWN!
            else:   # Some required stuff is still missing, so we show a corrected error message
                message = _('the following arguments are required: %s') % ', '.join(newArgs)

        self.print_usage(sys.stderr)    # Original method behavior
        args = {'prog': self.prog, 'message': message}
        self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
```

The new method first checks whether the error is because arguments are missing from the command line (see [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Lib/argparse.py#l1971) for the code that generates the error). If so, the method gets the names of the arguments from the error message and puts them into a list (`missingArgs`).

Then, we iterate over this list and check which arguments should be skipped, and which are still required. To determine which arguments to skip, we compare them against `skip_list`. It is a field in our `ArgumentParser` subclass that should contain the names of the arguments to skip even when they are required by the parser. Please note that arguments that happen to be in `skip_list` are removed from it when they are found.

If there are still required arguments that are missing from the command line, the method throws a corrected error message. If all the missing arguments should be skipped, however, the method returns.

**WARNING!** The original definition of `ArgumentParser.error` states that if it is overridden in a subclass **it should not return**, but rather exit or raise an exception. Therefore, what is shown here is potentially unsafe and may cause your program to crash, your computer to catch fire or worse - **IT MAY EVAPORATE ALL YOUR TEA**. However, it *seems* like in this particular case (missing required arguments) it is safe to return from the method. But it might not be. You have been warned.

In order to fill `skip_list` we could use code like this:

```py
class SpecialHelp(argparse._HelpAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        parser.print_help()
        print()
        for action in parser._actions:
            if action != self and action.required:
                parser.skip_list.append(argparse._get_action_name(action))
```

This particular class imitates the built-in `help` action, but instead of exiting it inserts all the remaining required arguments into `skip_list`.

Hope my answer helps and best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

It may be ugly, but that is what I normally do.

```
def print_list():
    the_list = ["name1", "name2"]
    return "{0}".format(the_list)

...
parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", action='version',
                    version=print_list(), help="print the list")
```